# ASP.NET MVC C# : HiddenFor to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, strongly-typed-view, html.hiddenfor

I have the following markup and code.

View:

```
@model WealthRef.Models.ViewModels

<td style="width: 100px;color:black" id="tdfromDatevalue">
if (Model != null)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.DropDownModels.FromDateModels.SelectedNode,
        new SelectList(Model.DropDownModels.FromDateModels.FromDateValues, 
                       "Code", "CodeDescription"),
        new { id = "ddlFromDateValues", 
              @class = "chosen-select",
              data_placeholder = "Select Date...", 
              style = "white-space:nowrap;width:100px;" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.FromDate, new { id = "hdnFromDate" })
}
</td>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$("#ddlFromDateValues").on("change", function () {
    var fromDate = $(this).val();
    $("#ddlFromDateValues").val(fromDate).trigger("chosen:updated");
    $("#hdnFromDate").val(fromDate);
});
</script>
<td>
    <a class="btn" href="@Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "WealthRef")" id="btnRun"
       style="color:White" onclick="return Validate();">Run</a>
</td>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    load();
});

function load() {
    $("#hdnFromDate").val($("#ddlFromDateValues").find("option:selected").val());
}
</script>
```

Model:

```
namespace WealthRef.Models
{
    public class ViewModels
    {
        public string FromDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult ExportToExcel(ViewModels model)
{
    string FromDate = model.FromDate;
}
```

I expected to get the `FromDate` from the hidden field, which is from the selected item from the `@Html.DropDownListFor`, but I got null.

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: `model =\>` <-- This is not valid C# Razor.

Comment: Your `<script>` elements are really messed-up... you probably should rectify that first.

Comment: @Dai No such expression in code.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works.

View:

```
<td style="width:80px; color:black; padding-right: 20px; " id="tdfromDatevalue">
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.DropDownModels.FromDateModels.SelectedNode, new SelectList(Model.DropDownModels.FromDateModels.FromDateValues, "Code", "CodeDescription"), new { id = "ddlFromDateValues", @class = "chosen-select", data_placeholder = "Select Date...", style = "white-space:nowrap;width:100px;" })
    }
</td>
<td>
    <form action="@Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "WealthRef")" method="post">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.GenericModels.fromDate, new { id = "hdnFromDate" })
        <input type="submit" value="Run" class="btn" style="color:White; font-size:13px; padding:6px 24px;" onclick="return Validate();" />
    </form>
</td>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var fromDate = $("#ddlFromDateValues").val();
    $("#hdnFromDate").val(fromDate);
    $("#ddlFromDateValues").val(fromDate).trigger("chosen:updated");
});
</script>
```

Model:

```
namespace WealthRef.Models
{
    public class ViewModels
    {
        public GenericModel GenericModels { get; set; }
    }
    public class GenericModel
    {
        public string fromDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult ExportToExcel(ViewModels model)
{
    string FromDate = model.GenericModels.fromDate;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**